# Static alarm manager

Tags: android

In my app i use a repeating AlarmManager. I've create a class for each timer; i've declared them static because i need to cancel that timer in different class of my app.

Here's the code:

```
public class TimerSyncOff {

public static final String intentExtra = "SyncOff";

public static void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, getIntent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    long trigger = 800000;
    long interval = 900000;



    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, trigger,interval, pi);

}

public static void Stop(Context context)
{ 
    try{
        AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, getIntent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        am.cancel(pi);

    }catch (Exception e){}  

}

private static Intent getIntent(){
    Intent i = new Intent(intentExtra);
    return i;
}
```

This works fine if i try to cancel the timer shortly after i have run the app; but if i try to cancel it like after a day that it run, no error are trown but timer did not stop and keep run.
Am i doing something wrong? Thanks!